# App does not install from Play Store on devices with Android 12 and above

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-app-bundle, android-12

I faced the following problem with my application - it can not be installed from Play Store on devices with Android 12 and above (error dialog from Play Store app at the bottom of the post).

The problem only appeared recently, presumably from the version 31.9.13-21 [0] [PR] 467268234 of Google Play Store.

Some other facts:

- Installing application from Android Studio using option "APK from app bundle" in run configuration works fine.
- Installing universal APK from Google Play Console works fine.
- Installing APK using `bundletool` works fine.
- Removing Play Store updates fixes the ptoblem. Updates can be removed from Play Store app settings.

Logcat contains the following error when installing from Play Store: *INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Full install must include a base package*. It seems that this error is thrown by Android system's class, more specifically [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/2c43c33/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageInstallerSession.java#348) (google source). As far as I understand, this means that invalid set of apks is generated from bundle, without main (or base apk).

App module's `build.gradle.kts` snippet (without dependencies):

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    kotlin("android")
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
    id("google-play-publisher")
    id("appcenter")
    id("com.huawei.agconnect")
    id("app-gallery-publisher")
}

android {
    compileSdk = 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.some.example"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 30
        versionCode = Versions.versionCode
        versionName = Versions.versionName
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        ndk {
            abiFilters.addAll(setOf("armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"))
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility(JavaVersion.VERSION_11)
        targetCompatibility(JavaVersion.VERSION_11)
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isShrinkResources = true
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
            proguardFiles(*fileTree("$rootDir/proguard").files.toTypedArray())
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("release")
        }
        getByName("debug") {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("debug")
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude("META-INF/LICENSE.md")
        exclude("META-INF/LICENSE-notice.md")
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }

    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
}
```

App module's `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.some.example">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:node="remove"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage"/>

    <application
        android:name="AppName"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup">
        <activity
            android:name="SomeActivityName"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="somescheme"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" tools:targetApi="m">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="some.host"
                    android:pathPrefix="/prefix" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="some.host"
                    android:path="/path/"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

[image]

Comment: 01. Try running it on Android 12 Device from Android Studio. 02. Post your Manifest.xml

Comment: 01. Running app on Android 12 from Android Studio (using app bundle) works without any problem. 02. Done

Comment: You seem to suggest this is a Play Store bug. If that's the case, reaching out to Play developer support might be more useful.

Comment: @Pierre already done :) https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/244621253. I just wanted to draw more attention here.

Comment: @vadim Did you manage to figure out any additional information? Started facing the same issue with the latest updates. Downgraded to play store v28.8.17-21

Answer (score 0):

Update you  compileSdk and targetSdk to 33 in your build.gradle.kts file.